# Can nuxt js develop with server language?

Tags: nuxt.js

I started using nuxt js . 
It is running on own URL localhost:3000
So I can't develop with my local project together - 'say laravel running on localhost:8000 '.
So if I use nuxt , must I use server side as a API ?
Or is there a way to develop together on same url ?

Answer (score 1):

> So if I use nuxt , must I use server side as a API ?

I would say yes, as it creates your complete frond end app (complete html output inlcuding client side routing).

> Or is there a way to develop together on same url

Because it creates the complete app it wouldn't make sense I guess. But if you're thinking about interweaving it with your Laravel app I would go for plain [vue.js](http://vuejs.org) as it is easy to integrate into an existing app and templates and with some configuration you can also work with the development tools on the same domain. Let me know, I can share my setup.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what you wanna do.

If you want a project with server side redering, then you have to use nuxt on your full project.

If you want to use Nuxt only to develop your front side, then you can add a lib/framework (like Laravel).

:)